# InnoDB not starting

Tags: mysql, innodb

I tried to start mysql service on xampp and is giving me the following error:

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 19:17:07  [mysql]     This may be due
>   to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  19:17:07  [mysql]   improper
>   privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 19:17:07 
>   [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 19:17:07 
>   [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 19:17:07  [mysql]   If
>   you need more help, copy and post this 19:17:07  [mysql]  entire log
>   window on the forums

This is the log of the ERROR:

> 2019-10-01 19:17:04 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or
>   you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery. 2019-10-01 19:17:04 0 [Note]
>   Server socket created on IP: '::'. 2019-10-01 19:17:04 0 [ERROR]
>   InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   tablespace but not the InnoDB log

I tried to restart windows several times, but the error keeps there. The BD I have is the default that comes with xampp.

Any suggestion is really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried almost everything trying to fix the SQL problem.
Finally, we have coppied the xammp files and reinstall it.
Then we created a new database and import the files and, it took us the whole day, but finally it worked.